# Only UEFI-Usb showing, how to force legacy for live usb?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, usb, uefi

I have made a live usb for Ubuntu MATE 16.04. When I go into the boot menu by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> on startup, only the UEFI usb option is there. My system, as per the System Information, is a legacy system. How can I make the legacy live usb option appear in the boot menu?

Comment: Check in Bios menu ..turn on legacy support and set highest priority to usb

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to force when you're booting to a live media.  Just boot to it.  The choice is in your bios.  The live media will recognize what you have set in your bios and actually boot based on that choice.

When you start to perform the install, if you have booted to the UEFI mode it will inform you that it's installing in that mode.

You can verify the actual mode you have booted to by examining the dmesg file.

```
$ dmesg | egrep "EFI v"
```

The out put will show you the EFI version... something similar to:

```
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.31 by American Megatrends
```

If the output is blank you have booted to `legacy` mode.

You wouldn't be able to boot into `UEFI` without having support for it in your BIOS.